# How should I enlarge 2 holes in the top plate of a lally column to match beam holes. The four holes were incorrectly measured. See Photo

Tags: structural, steel, diy-vs-pro

GC removed rusted lally column, but they screwed up and only 2 holes aligned enough to bolt. Remaining 2 holes have to be drilled out to align with my beam that holds up the house. Told GC not to touch my beam. So what to use to drill out top plate only with series of smaller bits for black areas indicated? If smaller drill bits are used, which is best, titanium, cobalt, or other. Any advice appreciated.

[image: Lally Column meets beam]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvRhd.jpg)

Comment: Measurements can sometimes get messed up.  Why tell the GC to leave the column alone. It sounds like he would have drilled it just as you intend to do.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I want him to enlarge the 2 holes on the top plate of the column, but not touch my beam. The easiest way for him would be to place a same sized drill bit in the top plate holes, and use them as a guide to drill into the flange of my beam. I don't want him to do that, as it will reduce the strength of the bottom flange of my beam. I want him to match the top flange of the new column to my existing beam holes.

Comment: can you remove it and then work on it

Answer (score 1):

That's a job best done with files, practically speaking. When you file out enough room to use larger files, use them, they will work faster, but you're going to have to start fairly small.

Or, have it done right by the contractor who screwed up - temporary supports, remove the column, make a pattern of the holes and know which way is up, apply to the top of a new column, drill holes in the new column top, take the column with the goofed up holes away... And if they won't, hire one who will, and send the first one (or their insurance) the bill.

Comment: Thank you for your answer